# Scan disk runs on every boot with Windows XP

Tags: windows, chkdsk, scan-disk

I have four drives on my computer. The problem is that each time I start the computer the scan disk check (CHKDSK) runs for a drive even if I shut down my computer properly. I ran the thorough scan disk check but still for that drive, the scan disk check is always performed no matter what.

I wonder what is wrong although everything is fine and accessible along with drive data. Could you guys please help me out of this?

I am using Windows XP SP2

**Edit**

With reply to comment below, the setting for the registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Contro l\
Session Manager\BootExecute
```

is set to:

```
chkvdisk autocheck autochk *
```

And I am not sure what does it mean, is this same in your case too? What is the default value for that registry key?

As for `chkdsk /f`, I get the following message:

```
Chkdsk cannot run because the volume is in use by another
process.  Chkdsk may run if this volume is dismounted first.
ALL OPENED HANDLES TO THIS VOLUME WOULD THEN BE INVALID.
Would you like to force a dismount on this volume? (Y/N)
```

I am not sure what it means especially the line `ALL OPENED HANDLES TO THIS VOLUME WOULD THEN BE INVALID.`. So, I am afraid and I do not run `chkdsk/f` because of data loss, etc.

Please Help

Thanks

Comment: What do you have set here HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Contro l\Session Manager\BootExecute?

Comment: @DwightSampsonite: Well, it is set to chkvdisk
autocheck autochk *

Comment: You mean check disk and not scan disk right? Scan disk was the Win 9x tool for FAT volumes.

Comment: @MarkM: I mean CHKDSK and problem drive is ntfs. Other drives are also ntfs but there is no problem with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a vanilla XP, the value of the BootExecute registry key is:

```
autocheck autochk *
```

The file chkvdisk in your registry entry is, according to the article [Chkvdisk not found](http://horizondatasys-forum.com/rollback-rx/600-chkvdisk-not-found.html), part of the [RollBack Rx](http://www.horizondatasys.com/177440.ihtml) product, which is an instant PC recovery software.

If you have RollBack Rx installed, it might explain why the hard disk is in constant use.
Let me know if this is the case.

**EDIT**

The RollBack Rx knowledge-base contains this article:
[Rollback is causing a repetitive CHKDSK](http://support.horizondatasys.com/ics/support/default.asp?deptID=4443)

After announcing that a CHKDSK problem is impossible, the article does actually explain how it can happen. 
I personally find the following paragraphs to be really frightening:

> Rollback Rx ... rather than copy the data
>   somewhere else, declares the hard
>   drive Sectors where the data is
>   currently located as “protected”. It
>   subsequently redirects any attempts to
>   change that sector. It does
>   this by attaching a “filter” to the
>   Windows driver.
>
> So, for example, if WFM (*Windows File Manager?*) wants to write
>   to sector 100, Rollback detects the
>   write, determines that a snapshot
>   protects sector 100, and redirects the
>   write to an open sector (say, 200) and
>   creates a reference in its own Disk
>   Map. Any subsequent read to Sector 100
>   is also redirected to Sector 200.
>
> **Alternately, a hard power loss just at the very microsecond that Rollback
>   is flushing its Disk Map from memory
>   to disk can cause a Disk Map Error as
>   well as, very likely, a CHKDSK. In
>   this case, the CHKDSK  run will
>   conclude successfully, but this does
>   not fix the Rollback Disk Map anomaly,
>   because the Map is invisible to
>   Windows.**

Conclusion: RollBack Rx becomes your disk manager, rather than Windows.
In fact, Windows has no idea what's happening to its own hard disk.

The above article contains a section titled "Find and Fix Snapshot Problems", that's supposed to fix these same problems that the same article previously denounced as urban myths. Not having RollBack Rx installed on my computer, I have no way of verifying whether they really work, but you certainly won't find anything better.

All I can remark as regarding installing RollBack Rx on my own computer is :
**Over my dead body!**

Comment: @harrymc: That's the exactly the case, I have rollback installed but this problem has never happened before with it and i wonder how to do away with it.

Comment: @Sarfraz Ahmed: See my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the dirty flag is not being cleaned. try running chkdsk /f from command prompt.

Comment: You should probably use /r instead of /f in this case, so that bad blocks will also be discovered. /r implies /f

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you run chkdsk from the recovery console, when there won't possibly be any other processes trying to interfere with it? You may also want to do a full hard drive test with some sort of diagnostic software... if the hard drive is repeatedly being marked dirty, it may be on the verge of failing, in which case you'll want to replace it asap.